# prevent child window from being caught by popup blocker

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child

I have a function which upon click, it checks some information with a `$.get()` call before it can know if it should open a child window. It works fine, only that, because the function which opens the child window was not directly from the click event, it will be considered a pesky unwanted popup. Does anyone know of a work-around or a way to prove to the browser that it is a wanted window? Thanks.

```
$('#send').click(function(){

     $.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
     $.get('test3.html',function(data){
   if(data == "processing"){
      alert("still processing");
  }else{
            childPage = window.open("test.html","send","width = 300,height = 300");
         }
     });
});
```

Comment: Have your users add your site to the exception list or rethink your design. If there were "ways" around it, that would defeat the purpose of a pop up blocker.

Comment: i think the modern approach to this is to use a <div> overlay and use ajax for updates. popups are REALLY annoying for users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be more reliable to pop up the window immediately (to show the user something's hapenning) with a loading screen. Then in the ajax handler you can redirect the popup to the correct page.

That said, popups in general are a bad idea. Is there no way you could do this another way?

Comment: not really, I am using the child window to upload, allowing the user to browse the parent page while the files are uploading

Answer (score 1):

I know that I'm not exactly answering what you want, but I found this way more appealing in general than a normal pop up, and gaining way more control.

I'm talking about using a plugin like fancybox, http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples
witch allows you to embed iframes, or any other content you want. I'm pretty sure loading an iframe like this would be much easier than trying to sneek around browser limitations.

Comment: interesting, I'll check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know of a work-around or a way to prove to the browser that it is a wanted window

This will mean changing the browser settings, these are there to prevent what you are trying to achieve so unfortunately to my knowledge there is no way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of open a new popup, you also can try simulate a popup window via  tag. Try [this](http://demo.mysamplecode.com/JavaScript/pages/popupBox.jsp)